# Стандартизированное меню "Пуск" в Windows 10 для всех пользователей в домене

Tags: windows-10, windows-server, group-policy

Стоит задача сделать всем пользователям стандартизированное меню "Пуск" в Windows 10. Нашел такую функцию в GPO: User Configuration/Policies/Administrative Templates/Start Menu and Taskbar/"Start Layout".

Почитал мануал (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/customize-and-export-start-layout), настроил нужное меню "пуск" (удалил все ненужные плитки, оставил и сгруппировал только то, что нужно) через PowerShell удачно выгрузил XML файл, положил на видное всем место и прописал путь до него в политике.

В итоге отработали только ярлыки на латинице, кириллицу он почему-то не понимает, в частности не хочет засовывать в меню пуск "Мой компьютер", "Документы", "Битрикс 24" и т.д, вместо них просто пустое место.

Что я пробовал и это не помогло:
1) Указывать в XML-файле названия на английском: Desktop, Documents, Downloads.
2) Ставить на сервер с GPM русский языковой пакет.